# Minder vs. niedrig

Tags: difference

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen **minder** und **niedrig**? Beide bedeuten "low" im Englischen. Welches würde man in den folgenden Fällen verwenden:

- low altitude
- low wages
- lower intelligence

und warum?

Comment: Ich würde die Frage um "gering" erweitern.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the word "niedrig" in all your examples, or "niedriger" (comparative) for the last example.

The word "minder" is usually used in compound words, and not for low altitude, but in the meaning low quantity/quality. For some examples, see [here](https://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/minder). "Minder" alone can be used as a negation "nicht minder" (not less) but rarely alone. The verb "mindern" (to decrease) can be used for many things, but again not altitude.

In compound words it can be used for "minderjährig" (not of age), "minderwertig" (low value) and many other words. "Niedrig" would not fit in those cases.

Comment: Minderwertig does not mean low value, but inferior or of low quality.

Comment: I would translate "mindern" with "reduce" rather then "decrease"

Answer (score 0):

*minder* ist eine veraltete Version von *weniger*, auch wenn Duden von einem normalen Adverb spricht, d. h.  es schwingt ein Komparativ mit: *minderbegabt* heißt eben weniger begabt als der Durchschnitt.

Wenn man sich nicht extra gehoben ausdrücken will, wie in

> trug Abteilung B nicht minder zum Geschäftsergebnis bei...

würde ich von der Verwendung abraten.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: Aber der Ausdruck *minderwertig* ist keineswegs gehobene, sondern ganz normale Sprache. Und in juristischem Kontext ist der *minderschwere* Fall ein Fachausdruck, bei dem keine Ausweichmöglichkeit besteht.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf Daß Komposita mit *minder* unauffällig sind, spricht nicht dagegen, daß alleinstehendes *minder* veraltet ist.